# SELECT NOT IN AND IN

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have this query

```
SELECT COUNT(RoomType) as Available_Rooms 
  FROM Table1 
 WHERE RoomNumber NOT IN (SELECT RoomNumber FROM Table2) 
 GROUP 
    BY RoomType
```

This Query Select only those rooms that are Available. 
How can I modify it to get the NOT available rooms. 
I tried to use

```
SELECT COUNT(RoomType) as Available_Rooms
  FROM Table1 
 WHERE RoomNumber IN (SELECT RoomNumber FROM Table2) 
 GROUP 
    BY RoomType
```

to fetch them, but how can I use these two queries for me to echo all of them in a table in php.

Comment: and what happened. how did it fail/error/bad output..

Comment: So you have two queries. The one fetches successfully the rooms that are available and the other those that aren't available. And your question is how to display both of them (Available AND Unavailable) in the same (HTML possibly?) table. Am I right?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: there is finished solution of RamRaider http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/760b0/1

Comment: Sir @Arkoudinos yes that what i want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the tables this remains untested but you could try something along the lines of the following:-

```
select *, count(*) as 'Available_Rooms'
    case
        when `RoomNumber` not in ( select `RoomNumber` from `Table2` ) then
            'Available'
        else
            'Not Available'
    end as 'availability'
from `Table1`
group by `RoomType`
```

Comment: Thnk you sir... i just forgot to put a "," after the 'Available_Rooms' that why i have an error. but still you solved my problem. Thank you Very Much